# Imitate pressing keyboard F-keys using a Perl script

Tags: windows, perl, keystroke

Is there a way that I can imitate the pressing of a function key (F1-F12) from a Perl script on Windows 7?

I have a program that requires F7 to be pressed in order to stop it.

I have tried killing the program process, but that doesn't stop the process cleanly.

Comment: You can try using this module:  use Win32::GuiTest qw(SendKeys IsKeyPressed); http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.60/lib/Win32/GuiTest/Examples.pm#eg/keypress.pl

Comment: What operating system are you using?  This can matter.

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: How are you starting this program in the first place? The difficult part isn't imitating the key press, but informing the appropriate process of the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, [Win32::GuiTest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest) can do what you want.  They have [several examples](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest::Examples) of using SendKeys to press function keys.

On Unix the situation is both easier and harder.  Function keys are usually mapped in a terminal to send several characters.  You can find out what they are using `ord` and sprintf to get their hex values (easier to work with).  Here's an example of "kj" as a simple example, then F1 through F7.

```
$ perl -wle 'while(<>) { chomp; print join ", ", map { sprintf "%x", ord } split //, $_ }'
kj
6b, 6a
^[OP
1b, 4f, 50
^[OQ
1b, 4f, 51
^[OR
1b, 4f, 52
^[OS
1b, 4f, 53
^[[15~
1b, 5b, 31, 35, 7e
^[[17~
1b, 5b, 31, 37, 7e
^[[18~
1b, 5b, 31, 38, 7e
^[[19~
1b, 5b, 31, 39, 7e
```

[ASCII 1b](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ascii+table) is the escape character (represented on the terminal by a `^[`).  5b is `[`, and so on.  So you can print those strings to the program's input or to the tty.  For example, F8 would be "\x{1b}[19~".

Why are F1-F4 different?  The [VT100 terminal](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php), upon which this is all based, only had four function keys.  The later [VT220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT220) added the rest.

There's probably a module to take care of this for you, but I can't find it.